# How to split a string based on the <br> tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a recipe website and I am finding trouble trying to separate the string into different sentences after the `<br>` tag.

For a better understanding of the problem, I will show you the code and the output that I am talking about.

The following is the HTML snippet I am working on.

```html
<div class="opskriften">
          <p class="h3">Ingrediensliste</p>
          <p></p>
<p>100 g. mælkechokolade<br>20 g. mini marshmallows<br>40 g. saltede peanuts</p>
<p>

        </p></div>
```

I want to somehow separate every ingredient after the `<br>` tag so I can then separate the strings even further so I can eventually get a table with 3 different columns (amount, unit, ingredient). The following code is what I used to get that certain `<p>` tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests 
    r = requests.get("site")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    ingredients = soup.find('div', class_='opskriften')
    ingredientslist = ingredients.select_one("p:nth-oftype(2)")
    print(ingredientslist)
```

The output being the following:

```
<p>100 g. mælkechokolade<br/>20 g. mini marshmallows<br/>40 g. saltede peanuts</p>
```

How can I separate those ingredients so I can then be able to apply a regular expression to match everything and put it in the right columns as described above?

I tried using regex as shown below, but I am getting the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` so I suppose that I need to separate these in order to apply that properly.

```
pattern_text=r'(?P<amount>\d+):\s+(?P<unit>\w+):\s+(?P<ingredient>\w+)'
pattern=re.compile(pattern_text)

match=pattern.match(ingredientslist)
match.groups()
```

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Is it necessary to use regular expressions? You could simply put the ingredients on a list with `split`: `ingredients_string.split('<br/>')`

Comment: @PabloRiutort - well, after splitting the sentences I will have to split them even further into 3 things: amount, unit and ingredient, therefore creating a table of this sort: Amount: 100 // Unit: grams // Ingredient: mælkechokolade. On another note, I followed your tip and added the split method as it follows: `ingredientslist = ingredients.select_one("p:nth-of-type(2)").get_text().split('<br/>')` but now the output is `['100 g. mælkechokolade20 g. mini marshmallows40 g. saltede peanuts']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression to separate all the ingredients inside the `p` tag, and use the `groupdict` function to output to a `key:value` pair, as you needed:

```
import re

s = "<p>100 g. mælkechokolade<br/>20 g. mini marshmallows<br/>40 g. saltede peanuts</p>"
r = re.compile(r"(?P<amount>\d+)\s+(?P<unit>\w+.)\s+(?P<ingredient>.+?(?=<))")

print([m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(s)])

#[{'amount': '100', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mælkechokolade'}, {'amount': '20', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'mini marshmallows'}, {'amount': '40', 'unit': 'g.', 'ingredient': 'saltede peanuts'}]
```

Comment: This is awesome! But unfortunately, in my case, I get the following error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. Most probably because `ingredientslist = ingredients.select_one("p:nth-of-type(2)").` is not of string or byte type. If I add `.text` it prints out an empty string. Any suggestion on how to fix this, as well? Thanks!

Comment: Putting the ingredientslist variable inside a string worked perfectly (`s = f"{ingredientslist}"`). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `.get_text()` with `separator` parameter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="opskriften">
          <p class="h3">Ingrediensliste</p>
          <p></p>
<p>100 g. mælkechokolade<br>20 g. mini marshmallows<br>40 g. saltede peanuts</p>
<p>

        </p></div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

ingredients = soup.find('div', class_='opskriften')

print (ingredients.get_text(separator=" ").strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Ingrediensliste 

 100 g. mælkechokolade 20 g. mini marshmallows 40 g. saltede peanuts
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe?

`a = "<p>100 g. mælkechokolade<br>20 g. mini marshmallows<br>40 g. saltede peanuts</p>"
print(a.replace("<br>"," "))`

and output:

```
<p>100 g. mælkechokolade 20 g. mini marshmallows 40 g. saltede peanuts</p>
```